# Uppercase filenames for images on webpage?

Tags: file, web

Is it OK to use uppercase filenames for images on a webpage? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filenames aren't shown to the user of your page so they can be however you want them to be.

Note, however, that it's important that the filenames exactly match between your HTML and your server. Although Microsoft servers are not case sensitive, Linux and other servers are.

It is conventional for images to be named in lower case; personally I find that more readable.